# How to remove img tag inside div to set background image? Waffle (amazonS3) generated link

Tags: css, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a problem with setting the background image inside a div tag.
This is the opening of the div tag.

```
  <div class="..." style='background-image: url("<%= book_img(book, :thumbnail) %>")'>
```

I have found out while inspecting this element that the problem is in the link.

```
<div class="..." style='background-image: url("<img src="https://myproject.s3.amazonaws.com/images/xxx.jpg">")'>
```

Inside `background-image: url()` there is another tag, an img tag. In the web developer tool, when I remove img tag and just leave the URL it works fine. Is there any way to make a workaround to make it work?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Why not use a `style.css` declaration for the class instead: `.myclass background-image: url(https://myproject.s3.amazonaws.com/images/xxx.jpg);`

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff This is a part of the code for listing products. Each product has different image so I cannot specify one exact picture.

Comment: It seems like the `book_img` function is returning an `<img>` tag which is not what you want. You want just the URL.

Comment: @PeacefulJames Yes, I am aware of that. I don't know if there is a workaround to remove the tag and leave only the URL inside that tag.

Comment: @PeacefulJames I came up to the conclusion that it will be easier and faster to copy and change a little bit that function. No need for further help. Thank you!

Comment: @Kapeusz That sounds like the correct thing to do. I suggest that if your new function is called `book_img_url` then you change `book_img` to call `book_img_url`.